# Create a Menu for users to choose whether they want to add/remove/search for numbers using an array

Tags: arrays, c

I want to build a simple user Menu for the user to add/remove and to search for numbers through an array. However, the problem that I am facing is that after successfully running the code and adding numbers to a global array. When choosing the remove option, It showed the list of the array but array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXYm8.png) is not the value of the array I entered, but a total length of the array instead.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXYm8.png). Please show me which parts that I coded or wrote wrong and excuse me for my bad english! Thank you so much in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int arr[] = {};
int arrLength = 0;

void add(int lengthCheck){
    int i,n,check = 0;
    do{
        printf("\nPlease add a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        fflush(stdin);
        
        arr[lengthCheck] = n;
        lengthCheck++;
        
        printf("\nNew Array:");
        for (i = 0; i < lengthCheck; i++){
            printf("\t%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        
        printf("\n\n Do you want to continue adding? (y = 0 | n = 1)\n");
        scanf("%d", &check);
        fflush(stdin);
    } while (check < 1);
    
    arrLength = lengthCheck;
    
}

void remove(int lengthCheck){
    int m, i, loop, count = 0;
    
    printf("\nArray:");
    for(loop = 0; loop < lengthCheck; loop++){
        printf(" %d", arr[loop]);
    }
    
    
    printf("\n\nPlease chooose a number to remove: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    for(loop = 0; loop < lengthCheck; loop++) {
        if(arr[loop] == m) {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    for(i=count; i<lengthCheck - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
    
    lengthCheck--;
    
    printf("\nNew array are : ");
    for(i=0; i<lengthCheck; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }
}


void search(int arrLength){
    int check, loop, t, u;
    printf("\nPlease enter a number to check if it exists in the array: ");
    scanf("%d",&check);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    for(loop = 0; loop < arrLength; loop++) {
        if(arr[loop] == check) {
            printf("\n\tPosition number %d in the array contains %d\n\n", t,check);
            u++;
        }
        t++;
    }
    
    printf("The number %d exist in %d position(s) of the array",check,u);
}


int main(){
    int ch, z;
    for (z = 0; z < 1;) {
        
        printf("Enter Choice: \n\t(0) for add \n\t(1) for remove \n\t(2) for search\n\t(3) for exit\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        fflush(stdin);
  
        switch(ch) {
            case 0:
                add(arrLength);
                break;
            case 1:
                remove(arrLength);
                break;
            case 2:
                search(arrLength);
                break;
            case 3:
                z = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0; 
    
}
```

Comment: Please do not post text as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: `int arr[] = {};` That's not going to work - it is a zero sized array. Arrays in C have a fixed size determined when it is declared and can not change size after that. You need to either use a fixed max sized array or use dynamic memory to allocate more memory as needed.

Comment: **Critical Warning:** The `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined-behavior. Only `stdout` is permissible to be flushed using this function.

Comment: And please don't reply with "but the code was working up to that point". Accessing invalid memory is Undefined Behaviour in C. UB means the behaviour is unpredictable. It may appear to "work" for some cases but can fail or change behaviour at any time.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot declare an empty array and just add values to it in C.

`int arr[] = {};`

You need to allocate space for your array upfront, or using malloc to allocate the memory for it later.

This will allocate memory space to store three ints in they array and initialize each element to zero:

`int arr[3] = {0};`

You will have to check that it never goes above the number of elements declared in the array. If you try to use more space than pre-allocated in the array, you are causing a buffer overflow and all it does is corrupt memory.